# How to Download HTML Pages of a WebSite, Based on a Time Stamp?

Tags: command-line, cygwin, wget, curl, timestamp

I know this might be a repeated question, and I'm sorry for that,
but I failed to find any answer for my problem .

I Just want to download the Pages html files, without any other contents,
 and (If possible) I want to make a time stamp option, to only download the "newer than.." pages
I think Wget Might be great for that . (I've CygWin and GNUWin32 installed on my system)

Any Help Please - Thanks In Advance...

Comment: Yes, wget is great for that. To call it periodically, you could use [AT](https://support2.microsoft.com/kb/313565).

Comment: Thanks bro for your reply, I think I didn't explain my problem quite well. what I want to do, is to only download the new html pages of that website, but calling the batch/command isn't a problem, because I'm gonna call it myself, so, there is no need to make that task scheduled . So, any suggestions ? - Thanks - Karim

Comment: wget has an option for that. Read [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html).